# php обрезать URL

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток всем, есть ссылка $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] такого вида **mvc/cabinet/user**, mvc/ это каталог в котором проект находится и его нужно обрезать с учетом того, что название каталога может быть любое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"учетом того, что название каталога может быть любого названия" - предполагаю, что размерность названия не известна.

Можно сделать так:

```
$url = explode('/','mvc/cabinet/user'); // $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
array_shift($url); // или array_slice($url, 1);
$url = implode('/',$url);
```

**UPD**

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = str_replace(КОНСТАНТА,'', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Comment: да название не известно, поэтому его поместил в константу в конфигурационном файле, и его нужно обрезать, т.е. константу, что бы остался такой вид cabinet/user

Comment: Если изменять константу, она уже таковой не останется. Пробуйте ответ

Comment: RaZik, в константе содержится только слово "mvc" в которой прописан каталог проекта, и с помощью этой константы обрезать из REQUEST_URI этот  "mvc", вот только не получается(

Comment: обновил ответ по комментарию

Comment: теперь заработало)

Comment: Если ответ решил вопрос - отметьте его

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75069/discussion-between-razik-and-).

Answer (score 0):

`$url = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/") + 1);`

Пояснение:
strpos возвращает положение первого вхождения строки "/" в строке $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Отсчёт начинается от нуля, поэтому прибавляем 1. Получаем число 4.
Затем берём часть строки функцией substr из строки $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], начиная с 4-го символа и до конца.